# do not fail spring container if bean does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 modules on project. One of them calls `common`. In this module i am trying to start Spring container. One of beans live in another module (`webapp`) and also i have a module `testapp`. So now, after deploying project on server (webapp and common) it is all OK, but if I try to deploy common and testapp it fails with exception:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class[...]
```

i whant to know if it is any possibility to ignore unexisting bean and run container? I am using xml configuration, no annotations. Due to business logic it should be exactly xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Spring profiles to determine when specific beans should be instantiated. For example you can have two profiles web (for common + webapp) and test (for common + testapp)

Then in your application context xml configuration define your beans as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

   <!-- define common beans here-->
     <beans profile="test">
         <!-- define test beans here-->
     </beans>
     <beans profile="web">
        <!-- define web beans here-->
     </beans>
</beans>
```

Then depending on how you launch your application you need to provide a system property named spring.profiles.active to provide the profile to use.

For example -Dspring.profiles.active=web or -Dspring.profiles.active=test

Comment: for more info about this solution follow the [link](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/08/using-spring-profiles-in-xml-config.html#.VwyzZzTBn1w)